# JAXB: serialize private fields and deserialize without a parameter-less contructor

Tags: serialization, jaxb, deserialization

The problem I have involves a pretty complex class structure but I managed to summarize the gist of it in the following simpler example. I need to be able to serialize an object of class **MyItem** (including private property 'text') and subsequently deserialize it without having a parameter-less constructor available and without being able to create one because it would totally mess up the current logic.

class **MyCollection**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="collection")
public class MyCollection {

    public MyCollection() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    private List<MyItem> items;

    public void addItem(String text) {
        this.items.add(new MyItem(text));
    }
}
```

class **MyItem**:

```
public class MyItem {

    public MyItem(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    private String text;
}
```

The first requirement (serialize **MyItem** including private property) is met out of the box and I get the following xml as a result:

```
<collection>
    <item text="FIRST"/>
    <item text="SECOND"/>
    <item text="THIRD"/>
</collection>
```

In order to meet the second requirement I decorated class **MyItem** with attribute **@XmlJavaTypeAdapter**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyItemAdapter.class)
public class MyItem {
  ...
```

and introduced classes **AdaptedMyItem**

```
public class AdaptedMyItem {

    private String text;
    public void setText(String text) { this.text = text; }
    @XmlAttribute
    public String getText() { return this.text; }
}
```

and **MyItemAdapter**

```
public class MyItemAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedMyItem, MyItem> {

    @Override
    public MyItem unmarshal(AdaptedMyItem adaptedMyItem) throws Exception {
        return new MyItem(adaptedMyItem.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMyItem marshal(MyItem item) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMyItem result = new AdaptedMyItem();
        result.setText("???"); // CANNOT USE item.getText()
        return result;
    }
}
```

but this is where I get stuck because in method **marshal** I cannot access **MyItem.text** and so I cannot use the standard approach for dealing with immutable classes in JAXB.

**Bottomline:** I would like to use the class adapter mechanism only when deserializing (because I need to invoke a non-parameterless constructor) but not when serializing (because I cannot access private properties). Would that be possible?

Comment: Why don't you add a getter for MyItem.text? - Otherwise, use the same technique the JAXB marshaller uses to obtain the private field String text.

Comment: Adding getters would certainly solve the issue but before relaxing some OOP principles (namely encapsulation) I wanted to look for a cleaner solution, if available. Besides, I might have to serialize an instance of a class belonging to a third party library, with no available sources.

Comment: If the getter has been omitted for a good reason, the field probably shouldn't be serialized. (E.g., consider a String implementation with an initial byte array offset.) Storing a value that cannot be retrieved in the usual way isn't very useful.